# Recycler view in a Fragment is showing up in emulator and some real time devices but not showing up in some real time devices

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

I am having a recycler view in one my fragment. The recycler view is showing up with the items in emulator and some real time devices but it is not showing up in some real time devices. I have kept this recycler view in a nested scroll view.

**Devices I'm able to see the recycler view**:One plus 6T(9), Realme

**Devices I'm not able to see the recycler view**: Vivo(8.1), Sony Xperia Z2(6.1)

My Fragment.xml Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/reminder_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:text="@string/refill_reminder"
    android:textColor="#031B54"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/refillReminder_card"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="14dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/reminder_label"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/reminder_label">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/refillName_heading"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:text="@string/refill_name"
            android:textColor="#090909"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/refillName_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/refillName_heading"
            android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="87dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/refillName_heading"
            android:text="@string/metamorphine"
            android:textColor="#090909"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/refillDueIn_heading"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/refillName_heading"
            android:layout_alignStart="@id/refillName_heading"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:text="@string/refill_due_in"
            android:textColor="#090909"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/refillDueIn_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@id/refillName_label"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/refillDueIn_heading"
            android:text="@string/_28_days"
            android:textColor="#090909"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nextRefillDate_heading"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/refillDueIn_heading"
            android:layout_alignStart="@id/refillDueIn_heading"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
            android:text="@string/next_refill_date"
            android:textColor="#090909"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nextRefillDate_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@id/refillDueIn_label"
             android:layout_alignBottom="@id/nextRefillDate_heading"
            android:text="@string/_12_5_2019"
            android:textColor="#090909"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/prescriptionHistory_card"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="14dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/refillReminder_card"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/refillReminder_card"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/refillReminder_card">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/history_image"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_history"
            android:contentDescription="TODO" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/history_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/history_image"
            android:text="@string/prescription_history"
            android:textColor="#031B54"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/prescriptionHistory_button"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_arrow_right_b" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/myMedicines_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
    android:text="@string/my_medicines"
    android:textColor="#031B54"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/prescriptionHistory_card" />

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/myMedicines_RecyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="14dp"
    android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/myMedicines_label"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false">

</androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

RecylerView CARD.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/myMedicines_card"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
android:elevation="3dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dosageForm_icon"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:contentDescription="TODO" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dosage_startDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/dosageForm_icon"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/apr_22_2019"
        android:textColor="#404040"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dosage_endDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/dosage_startDate"
        android:layout_alignStart="@id/dosage_startDate"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:text="@string/apr_30_2019"
        android:textColor="#404040"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/verticalSeperator_view"
        android:layout_width="13dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/dosageForm_icon"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_seperator" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/refillName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/verticalSeperator_view"
        android:text="@string/metamorphine"
        android:textColor="#404040"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="22dp"
        android:layout_height="18dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="7dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_more_horiz" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/weekday_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/refillName"
        android:layout_alignStart="@id/refillName"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/verticalSeperator_view">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sunday_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/weekday_bg_grey"
            android:text="@string/su"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/monday_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/sunday_label"
            android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/sunday_label"
            android:background="@drawable/weekday_bg_grey"
            android:text="@string/mo"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tuesday_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/sunday_label"
            android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/monday_label"
            android:background="@drawable/weekday_bg_grey"
            android:text="@string/tu"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/wednesday_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/sunday_label"
            android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/tuesday_label"
            android:background="@drawable/weekday_bg_grey"
            android:text="@string/we"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/thursday_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/sunday_label"
            android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/wednesday_label"
            android:background="@drawable/weekday_bg_grey"
            android:text="@string/th"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/friday_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/sunday_label"
            android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/thursday_label"
            android:background="@drawable/weekday_bg_grey"
            android:text="@string/fr"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/saturday_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/sunday_label"
            android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/friday_label"
            android:background="@drawable/weekday_bg_grey"
            android:text="@string/sa"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/timeline_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/weekday_view"
        android:layout_alignStart="@id/weekday_view"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_width="42dp"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp">

            <View
                android:id="@+id/horizontalSeperator_view1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
                android:background="#FBFBFB" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/time1_label"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textSize="10sp" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/subview1"
                android:layout_width="12dp"
                android:layout_height="12dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/time1_label"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:background="@drawable/timeline_bg_color" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/view2"
            android:layout_width="42dp"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/view1">

            <View
                android:id="@+id/horizontalSeperator_view2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
                android:background="#FBFBFB" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/time2_label"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textSize="10sp" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/subview2"
                android:layout_width="12dp"
                android:layout_height="12dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/time2_label"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:background="@drawable/timeline_bg_color" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/view3"
            android:layout_width="42dp"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/view2">

            <View
                android:id="@+id/horizontalSeperator_view3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
                android:background="#FBFBFB" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/time3_label"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textSize="10sp" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/subview3"
                android:layout_width="12dp"
                android:layout_height="12dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/time3_label"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:background="@drawable/timeline_bg_color" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/view4"
            android:layout_width="42dp"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/view3">

            <View
                android:id="@+id/horizontalSeperator_view4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
                android:background="#FBFBFB" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/time4_label"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textSize="10sp" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/subview4"
                android:layout_width="12dp"
                android:layout_height="12dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/time4_label"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:background="@drawable/timeline_bg_color" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Fragment Class

```
    public class PrescriptionFragment extends Fragment {

    Context thisContext;
    private RecyclerView myMedicineRecyclerView;
    private MyMedicinesAdapter myMedicinesAdapter;

    List<MyMedicine> myMedicineList;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        System.out.println("Inside prescription onCreateView");
        thisContext = container.getContext();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.prescription_fragment, container, false);
        myMedicineRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.myMedicines_RecyclerView);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(thisContext, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false);
        myMedicineRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Button presHistoryButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.prescriptionHistory_button);
        presHistoryButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(thisContext, "Prescription History Button Tapped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }


    // This refreshList() method is getting called from my Fragments main class
    public void refreshList(List<TreatmentObject> data) {
        System.out.println("Inside of refreshList of Pres Fragment");
        System.out.println("Data size is" + data.size());
        System.out.println("Inside refreshList(data)" + data);
        myMedicineList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
            TreatmentObject treatmentObject = data.get(i);
            System.out.println(treatmentObject);
            int dosageImage;
            switch (treatmentObject.getFORM()) {
                case "Tablet":
                    dosageImage = R.drawable.ic_tablet_c;
                    break;
                case "Capsule":
                    dosageImage = R.drawable.ic_pills_c;
                    break;
                case "Bandage":
                    dosageImage = R.drawable.ic_bandage_c;
                    break;
                case "Concent...":
                    dosageImage = R.drawable.ic_medicine_c;
                    break;
                case "Drops":
                    dosageImage = R.drawable.ic_eyedrops_c;
                    break;
                case "Elixir":
                    dosageImage = R.drawable.ic_elixir_c;
                    break;
                case "Enema":
                    dosageImage = R.drawable.ic_enema_c;
                    break;
                case "Gel":
                    dosageImage = R.drawable.ic_gel_c;
                    break;
                case "Inhaler":
                    dosageImage = R.drawable.ic_inhaler_c;
                    break;
                case "Injection":
                    dosageImage = R.drawable.ic_syringe_c;
                    break;
                case "Kit":
                    dosageImage = R.drawable.ic_firsaidkit_c;
                    break;
                case "Spray":
                    dosageImage = R.drawable.ic_paintspray_c;
                    break;
                case "Syrup":
                    dosageImage = R.drawable.ic_syrup_c;
                    break;
                case "Tape":
                    dosageImage = R.drawable.ic_tape_c;
                    break;
                case "Tincture":
                    dosageImage = R.drawable.ic_tincture_c;
                    break;
                case "Wafer":
                    dosageImage = R.drawable.ic_wafer_c;
                    break;
                default:
                    dosageImage = R.drawable.ic_pills_c;
            }
            String startDate = null, endDate = null;
            if(treatmentObject.getStartDate() != null && treatmentObject.getStartDate() != "") {
                startDate = toISO8601UTCRepeat(fromISO8601UTCRepeat(treatmentObject.getStartDate()));
            }
            if(treatmentObject.getEndDate() != null && treatmentObject.getEndDate() != "") {
                endDate = toISO8601UTCRepeat(fromISO8601UTCRepeat(treatmentObject.getEndDate()));
            }
            String daysArray[] = new String[0];
            if(treatmentObject.getSCHEDULE() != null && treatmentObject.getSCHEDULE() != "") {
                if (treatmentObject.getSCHEDULE().equalsIgnoreCase("Daily")) {
                    daysArray = new String[]{"Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"};
                } else if (treatmentObject.getSCHEDULE().equalsIgnoreCase("Weekly")) {
                    if(treatmentObject.getDAYS() != null && treatmentObject.getDAYS() != "") {
                        String days = treatmentObject.getDAYS();
                        daysArray = days.split(", ");
                        System.out.println("Weekly Days Array is" + Arrays.toString(daysArray));
                    }
                }
            }
            String time1 = null, time2 = null, time3 = null, time4 = null;

            if (treatmentObject.getTIME1() != null && treatmentObject.getTIME1() != "" ) {
                time1 = toISO8601UTC(fromISO8601UTC(treatmentObject.getTIME1()));
            }
            if (treatmentObject.getTIME2() != null && treatmentObject.getTIME2() != "" ) {
                time2 = toISO8601UTC(fromISO8601UTC(treatmentObject.getTIME2()));
            }
            if (treatmentObject.getTIME3() != null && treatmentObject.getTIME3() != "" ) {
                time3 = toISO8601UTC(fromISO8601UTC(treatmentObject.getTIME3()));
            }
            if (treatmentObject.getTIME4() != null && treatmentObject.getTIME4() != "" ) {
                time4 = toISO8601UTC(fromISO8601UTC(treatmentObject.getTIME4()));
            }
            MyMedicine myMedicine = new MyMedicine(treatmentObject.getMedicineName(), dosageImage, startDate, endDate, daysArray, time1, time2, time3, time4, treatmentObject.getNOTE());
            myMedicineList.add(myMedicine);

            myMedicinesAdapter = new MyMedicinesAdapter(thisContext, myMedicineList);
            myMedicineRecyclerView.setAdapter(myMedicinesAdapter);
        }
    }

    public static String toISO8601UTC(Date date) {
        TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mma");
        df.setTimeZone(tz);
        return df.format(date);
    }

    public static Date fromISO8601UTC(String dateStr) {
        TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
        System.out.println(tz);
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SSS");
        df.setTimeZone(tz);
        try {
            return df.parse(dateStr);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            System.out.println("Inside catch exception");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static String toISO8601UTCRepeat(Date date) {
        TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy");
        df.setTimeZone(tz);
        return df.format(date);
    }

    public static Date fromISO8601UTCRepeat(String dateStr) {
        TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
        System.out.println(tz);
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        df.setTimeZone(tz);
        try {
            return df.parse(dateStr);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            System.out.println("Inside catch exception");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: show your recycler view adapter class.

Comment: @KaranKhurana I'm not able to add the code bcoz of the body limit 30000.How should I show you?

Comment: @KaranKhurana You can find my recycler view adapter code here https://shrib.com/#71t5-yWMNlzpHt6uiONK

Comment: why are you nesting recylcer inside a scroll view?

Comment: take out constraint layout from scrollview and adjust your layout. Mixing scrollview with recyclerview can cause display issues.

Comment: @UmarHussain My view contains some other elements along with Recycler view. I want the recycler view to move along with those elements instead of recycler view alone moving.

Comment: @UmarHussain I have taken out Constraint layout as you told and kept Relative layout in its place but still same issue